# inradius by feet of altitude

Tags: geometry

In the following question how they have got the value of angle OEF and in the next step how they have written the value of sine.

[image]

Comment: DEF is called the "orthic triangle" of ABC. It possesses many properties. See (http://www.math.washington.edu/~king/coursedir/m444a04/notes/orthic/www/Altitudes%20and%20Orthic%20Tri.htm).

Answer (score 1):

One can compute $F=\left({7\over5},{19\over5}\right)$ and $AE=FE={3\over\sqrt2}$.
It follows that triangle $AFE$ is isosceles and $\angle A =\angle AFE$, so that:
$$\angle OEF=\angle OEA-\angle AEF=90°-(180°-\angle A -\angle AFE)=
90°-(180°-2\angle A ).$$

The relation $\sin(2\angle A-90°)=r\sqrt2$ is obtained by dropping from $O$ the altitude $OH$ to $FE$, which is also the inradius. You have then
$$
\sin(\angle OEF)=\sin(\angle OEH)={OH\over OE}={r\over 1/\sqrt2}.
$$